# LocalTime parse method throws error when used with DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, localdate, localtime, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

Basically im want to apply a DateTimeFormatter with format 'hh:mm' to the value i get from 'zonedDateTime.toLocalTime()' object and store it as a LocalTime object, so that i get values like '08:00', the below code shows how i get the current time of a specific timezone, and im trying to convert it to a LocalTime called 'currentTime' while formatting it:

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm");

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(appTheme.getTimezone()));
        LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.parse(zonedDateTime.toLocalTime().toString(),formatter);
```

Now for some unknown reason i get the below error thrown from the last code line from above:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '15:32:03.824' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 5
    java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:441)
    io.apptizer.cafe.controller.CategoryController.getBusinessCategoryDetails(CategoryController.java:789)
    io.apptizer.cafe.controller.CategoryController.backwardCompatibilityCategories(CategoryController.java:387)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    io.apptizer.cafe.filter.SessionHandleFilter.doFilter(SessionHandleFilter.java:39)
```

I hope i explained my problem well, my main goal is to get the 'zonedDateTime.toLocalTime()' value in 'hh:mm' or 'HH:mm' format and store it as a LocalTime object, i just can achieve it because is error comes up,

would be good if someone can help, cheers!

Comment: `"15:32:03.824"` is not of format `"hh:mm"`.

Comment: yes, im trying to make the time given from 'zonedDateTime' into 'hh:mm' format, in that case how am i supposed to do it? @Turing85

Comment: Please [edit] the post and clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: `trying to convert it to a LocalTime [...] while formatting it` - Those are two very different things. What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Which representation (if not both) do you ultimately need?

Comment: @Izruo i edited rn, i need both, i need to store the value i get from 'zonedDateTime.toLocalTime()' as a LocalTime object in 'HH:mm' or 'hh:mm' format

Comment: There is a method [`toLocalDateTime()` in class `ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDateTime()). There are getters for [the hour](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getHour()) and [the minute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getMinute()) on `LocalDateTime`, and a [fitting factory method for `LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#of(int,int)).

Comment: @Turing85 isnt that a long process, because in the future i will be using multiple LocalTime values for time range comparisons, so ur saying for each i need to manually create LocalTIme objects by parsing a concatinated string value consisting hour and minutes?

Comment: @YeshanSanthush please read the links I provided. You have to parse nothing. From what your question said, you wanted to convert a `ZonedDateTime` to a corresponding `LocalTime` with only the hour- and minute-component set. I linked the resources to do exactly that. I question this approach and would just convert it to a correspondinig `LocalTime` by calling `toLocalTime()` on the `ZonedDateTime` and then format it accordingly when displayed.

Comment: @Turing85 There's also [`LocalTime#truncatedTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)), so one can alternatively use `toLocalTime().truncatedTo(TimeUnit.MINUTES)`.

Comment: @Turing85 i question this approach and ....., thats exactly what i have done above in my code, and format it when display, i dont even want to display, i want this to be stored as a LocalTime object so that i can use this for time range comparisons. why isnt my implementation working, the logic in my code is correct right

Comment: No it is not, please see [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678057/localtime-parse-method-throws-error-when-used-with-datetimeformatter?noredirect=1#comment119624187_67678057). You convert the `ZonedDateTime` into a `LocalDateTime`, THEN convert this into a `String`, THEN re-parse that date-`String` (which has format `"hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS"`) with the format-`String` `"hh:mm"`, which obviously fails.

Comment: @Turing85 oh thnx, i get ur point, thnx for the help dude, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```java
ZonedDateTime
.now(
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" )
)
.toLocalTime()
```

Or just:

```
LocalTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) )
```

## Details

Your problems include:

- Your formatting pattern `hh:mm` does not match your input `15:32:03.824`.
- `hh:mm` is using the wrong codes. The `hh` means 12-hour clock, but your input is clearly 24-hour clock.

### ISO 8601

Your input format complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for a time-of-day.

### `LocalTime`

The *java.time* classes use standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern. Just parse as a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) object.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "15:32:03.824" ) ;
```

Your larger goal is unclear, but I suspect you want the current time-of-day as seen in a particular time zone. If so, just use `LocalTime.now` while passing the time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.now( z ) ;
```

If you have a moment represented as a `ZonedDateTime`, simply call `toLocalTime` to extract a `LocalTime` object.

```
LocalTime lt = myZonedDateTime.toLocalTime() ;
```

Tip: You seem to be caught in thinking only in terms of string manipulations. Think instead of learning and using smart objects of the classes found in the industry-leading *java.time* framework built into Java 8 and later. See the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) by Oracle, free-of-cost. Notice how the **code above uses no strings** to do its work.

### Truncating

You said:

> so that i get values like '08:00',

If you mean you want to clear the minutes and seconds to zero, [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.HOURS ) ;
```

### Database

You commented:

> i need to store the value i get from 'zonedDateTime.toLocalTime()' as a LocalTime object in 'HH:mm' or 'hh:mm' format

If you mean store in a database, your database table should be defined as the type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIME` rather than a textual type. Then pass your `LocalTime` object via JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , lt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalTime lt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalTime.class ) ;
```

You commented:

> i will be using multiple LocalTime values for time range comparisons

Use a pair of `LocalTime` objects with JDBC to query columns of type `TIME`. For example, let's look for rows that are marked for the lunch hour.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.NOON ;
LocalTime end = LocalTime.of( 13 , 0 ) ;
```

The SQL would look something like this, where `?` is a placeholder for a value to be substituted as part of a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM some_table_
WHERE time_of_day_ !< ? 
AND time_of_day_ < ? 
;
```

Notice that `!<`, meaning "is not less than", is a shorter way of asking "is equal to or greater than".

Java code would be:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , start ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , end ) ;
```

Comment: I didnt mean store in database, i want to store it as a LocalTime object

Answer (score 1):

## [You can NOT create a formatted Date-Time object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66664791/10819573)

As described in the above link, you need to format the time into the string with the pattern of your choice. Note that `hh` corresponds to 12-hour time (i.e. AM/PM time) and therefore, you should use `a` with it. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for more details.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter24Hour = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTimeFormatter formatterAmPm = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        LocalTime localTime = zonedDateTime.toLocalTime();
        
        String currentTime24HourFormat = formatter24Hour.format(localTime);
        String currentTime12HourFormat = formatterAmPm.format(localTime);

        System.out.println(currentTime24HourFormat);
        System.out.println(currentTime12HourFormat);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
21:40
09:40 PM
```